# Do JupyterLab workspaces persist between reboots?

Tags: json, url, jupyter-lab

Do JupyterLab workspace persist between server restarts and reboots?

There is a file format for this here: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#workspace-file-format but there isn't any information about where they are stored.

The other reason I'm asking is that I'd like to be able to bookmark projects so they are easier to find.

P.S. Apologies if this is the wrong StackExchange to be asking the question in, if so, please move it to the correct StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, they usually persist, but only one workspace per all virtual environments and like with settings those are stored in `.jupyter` in home directory for me (which annoys me a bit, I would like to have them per-virtual environment).

For me the path is `~/.jupyter/lab/workspaces/` on Ubuntu, but this will vary depending on your installation. Generally use `jupyter --paths` and look in the `config` section for a directory named `lab`.

Comment: Any idea on how that plays out in Windows?

Comment: I have not used Jupyter on Windows but I would expect it to work similarly.